# Failed to resolve module specifier "stimulus-autocomplete"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

`Ruby 3.0.3`
`Rails 7.0.0.alpha2`

After following the instructions to [install](https://github.com/afcapel/stimulus-autocomplete#installation) and [usage](https://github.com/afcapel/stimulus-autocomplete#usage), I launch the server and I received this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "stimulus-autocomplete". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

```
# app/javascript/controllers/application.js
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import { Autocomplete } from "stimulus-autocomplete"
# and tried import { Autocomplete } from 'stimulus-autocomplete/src/autocomplete'

const application = Application.start()
application.register('autocomplete', Autocomplete)

// Configure Stimulus development experience
application.debug = false
window.Stimulus   = application

export { application }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use import maps, did you add `"stimulus-autocomplete"` in your config/importmap.rb so the lib can be imported?

```
pin "stimulus-autocomplete", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/stimulus-autocomplete@3.0.2/src/autocomplete.min.js"
```