# How to use stimulus components with rails import maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs, import-maps

I want to include this stimulus component into my brand new rails 7 app:
https://www.stimulus-components.com/docs/stimulus-dropdown

When I follow their setup approach, i get the following error in my browser console:
platforms#:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "stimulus-dropdown". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I found this article on stackoverflow:
[Failed to resolve module specifier "stimulus-autocomplete"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71489694/failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-stimulus-autocomplete)

which suggests to add a "pin" to my importmap.rb.

So i took the dropdown link from here https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/stimulus-dropdown

and put it into my importmap.rb by:

```
pin "stimulus-dropdown", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/stimulus-dropdown@2.0.0/dist/stimulus-dropdown.min.js"
```

But it doesnt work and displays a 404 in my browser console.

I hope someone can help, there must be an easy way to use stimulus-components in a brand new rails 7 app.

Answer (score 5):

i was also struggling but i have figured it out

first run -

```
./bin/importmap pin stimulus-dropdown
```

second create a stimulus controller called 'dropdown' -

```
rails g stimulus dropdown
```

then copy-paste the following code into the dropdown controller

```
import { Application } from '@hotwired/stimulus'
 import Dropdown from 'stimulus-dropdown'

 const application = Application.start()
 application.register('dropdown', Dropdown)
```

After you do all the above you are ready to use stimulus drop-down in your
views. for the view example check the docs on the site.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest adding it with `yarn` as well with `yarn add stimulus-dropdown`. This worked for me when I faced your issue.

Comment: the question was on Importmaps    http://meme.eq8.eu/so.jpg